# [ROS2] symbol lookup error and undefined symbol while using image transport cpp

Tags: ros2, c++, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi fellow developers,

I am a beginner at ROS2. After building the package and trying to run it I get the following error.

```
/home/jetson/ros2_ws/install/camera_pkg/lib/camera_pkg/camera_node: symbol lookup error: /home/jetson/ros2_ws/install/camera_pkg/lib/camera_pkg/camera_node: undefined symbol: _ZN15image_transport16create_publisherEPN6rclcpp4NodeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE17rmw_qos_profile_t
```

Honestly, do not know where to begin to tackle this issue. It seems to me an error with `image_transport.h`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362414/%5Bros2%5D-symbol-lookup-error-and-undefined-symbol-while-using-image-transport-cpp/) by [Majed](https://answers.ros.org/users/59911/majed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2020-09-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2020-09-28**:
you may post your Cmakelists.txt as well as package.xml, to me it seems that you are not correctly using find_package() and linking in the Cmakelists.txt. Are finding and linking `rclcpp`

**Comment by [Majed](https://answers.ros.org/users/59911/majed/) on 2020-09-28**:
@atas thank you for willingness to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@atas has given me a hint into how to solve the problem. As I was preparing to post the CMakelist, I noticed I had an extra `#ament_export_dependencies(.....)` below the `ament_target_dependencies(.....)`. This was the cause of the problem. I Just removed the `#ament_export_dependencies(.....)`

@atas thank you for willingness to help.

---

Originally posted by [Majed](https://answers.ros.org/users/59911/majed/) with karma: 55 on 2020-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ajoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/75173/ajoe/) on 2021-05-27**:
Hi I am getting the same error but not finding anything in my CMAkelist.txt... So please help me if there any other way

**Comment by [Majed](https://answers.ros.org/users/59911/majed/) on 2021-05-27**:
Post your CMakeList I will try my best to see what is the issue.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-05-28**:
@Ajoe please create a new question and post a link to it here. Comments/answers aren't a good place to be working on a new question